# Where is the best snorkelling in the Caribbean?

Tags: recommendations, destinations, caribbean

I am planning to go to the Caribbean in January.  I would like to be able to snorkel right off the beach, to avoid chartering a boat. Does anyone have suggestions on destinations (i.e. country, island, city, area)?

Comment: "Best" as in visibility? Variety? Cleanliness? Facility quality? Safety? Balance of the above? Something else? Do you prefer one amazing spot or several good ones? We aren't clairvoyant here.

Comment: Trying to strike a balance of criteria. I'm not an experienced freediver, so cave diving or other dangerous activities are not what I have in mind. Something safe for the whole family. Something with clean, clear waters, and a variety of underwater flora and fauna. Looking for an area (maybe a stretch of several dozen kilometres) with several good spots.

Comment: There are [23 island countries](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Caribbean_island_countries_by_population) and [many sovereign states on the Caribbean](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_sovereign_states_and_dependent_territories_in_the_Caribbean) - could you edit your question to make less broad by including more details? This is a Q/A website, not a forum, so we try to make questions where it can be answered definitively, not invoke discussion / arguments - 'best' could mean different things to someone who likes the blue hole in Belize, or prefers the beaches of Jamaica.

Comment: @MarkMayo: Well he does say he wants to snorkel right off the beach, so that rules out many places often regarded as "best", including the Blue Hole.

Comment: @hippietrail, agreed, not my best examples, but the statement still holds - it's a huge scope/range!

Comment: @AdamDunn: Are you going to the mainland of Mexico, Belize, Honduras or to island countries? Just to English-speaking destinations? Do you have budget constraints? Many resort destinations in the Caribbean are super expensive but many more affordable places will have less fully developed tourism facilities. Are you expecting to see coral or fish? Shipwrecks? Rare sights? Do you have lots of snorkelling experience and want the best of the best or are you an amateur who just wants the most bang for your buck?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Top Ten Places to Snorkel [(away.com)](http://away.com/features/top-ten-places-to-snorkel-beach-vacations-1.htm)

10. Utila, Honduras
11. Cozumel, Mexico
12. Grand Cayman, Cayman Islands
13. Virgin Gorda, British Virgin Islands
14. Anegada, British Virgin Islands
15. Curaçao, Netherlands Antilles
16. Dominica
17. Tobago Cays, St. Vincent and the Grenadines
18. Providenciales, Turks and Caicos
19. Bonaire, Netherlands Antilles

## The top 10 Caribbean snorkeling parks [(Active Travel on NBCNEWS.com)](http://www.msnbc.msn.com/id/27892516/ns/travel-active_travel/t/top-caribbean-snorkeling-parks/)

- Bonaire National Marine Park
- Belize, Glover’s Reef Marine Reserve
- Belize, Sapodilla Cayes Marine Park
- Little Cayman, Bloody Bay Marine Park
- Venezuela, Los Roques Archipelago National Park
- Dominica, Soufriere/Scott’s Head Marine Reserve
- St. Vincent + the Grenadines, Tobago Cays Marine Park
- St. Lucia, Soufriere Marine Management Area
- Bahamas, Exuma Cays Land and Sea Park
- Mexico, Banco Chinchorro Biosphere Reserve

## Best Snorkeling Beaches in the Caribbean Islands [(Caribbean Travel+Life)](http://www.caribbeantravelmag.com/gallery/best-snorkeling-beaches-caribbean-islands)

1. CANE, ST. CROIX, USVI
2. THE BATHS, VIRGIN GORDA
3. TRUNK BAY, ST. JOHN, USVI
4. 18 PALMS, BONAIRE
5. LIGHTHOUSE POINT, ELEUTHERA
6. PLAYA KALKI ,CURAÇAO
7. SMITH'S COVE ,GRAND CAYMAN
8. ANSE DE COLOMBIER, ST. BARTS
9. PLAYA DE LA CHIVA ,VIEQUES
10. WEST BAY BEACH, ROATAN, HONDURAS

## World's Best Islands for Snorkeling [(www.islands.com)](http://www.islands.com/gallery/worlds-best-islands-snorkeling)

1. Big Corn Island, Culebra
2. <s>Big Island, Hawaii</s>
3. <s>Bligh Water, Fiji Islands</s>
4. Bonaire, Netherlands Antilles
5. <s>Dry Tortugas National Park, Florida</s>
6. <s>Fernando de Noronha, Brazil</s>
7. Grand Cayman, Cayman Islands
8. Laughing Bird Caye, Belize
9. <s>Les Medes Islands, Spain</s>
10. <s>Maui, Hawaii</s>
11. <s>Menjangan Island, Bali, Indonesia</s>
12. <s>Misool, Raja Ampat, Indonesia</s>
13. <s>New Britain Island, Papua New Guinea</s>
14. North Bimini, Bahamas
15. <s>Plaza Sur, Galápagos Islands, Ecuador</s>
16. <s>Rurutu, French Polynesia</s>
17. <s>Sipadan Island, Borneo</s>
18. Soufriere, Dominica
19. <s>Uepi Island, Solomon Islands</s>
20. Utila, Bay Islands, Honduras
21. <s>Veligandu Island, Ari Atoll, Maldives</s>

## Top 5 Picks for Scuba Diving Off the Shore [(About.com Adventure Travel)](http://adventuretravel.about.com/od/wateradventures/tp/offshoredives.htm)

1. Bonaire -- an Underwater Art Museum
2. <s>Scuba Diving Off the Great Barrier Reef's Lady Elliot Island</s>
3. Scuba Divers Rank Cayman Islands a "Must Visit"
4. Curacao is Surrounded by Reefs and Walls
5. [Shorediving.com](http://Shorediving.com)

(Please edit this answer to `<s>`<s>strike out</s>`</s>` any items in the lists which are not in the Caribbean, or remove the strikeout from items which really are in the Caribbean.)

I've created a map of all these places using a web service I just discovered called [batchgeo](http://batchgeo.com/):

[image: Map of aggregated "top places to snorkel in the Caribbean"]

Comment: I've been in number 1 and 2 in away.com list. Her're my videos - Utils - http://youtu.be/uF1CSYFoQP4  Cozumel - http://youtu.be/Xo2nYhF1bCg

Comment: The best snorkeling place for me was Akumal - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tj_OzcWUbGY (Start from second 20 for Akumal)

Answer (score 0):

You are looking at Aruba; Montego Bay, Jamaica, Barbados and Tobago.  Of course there are many other Caribbean islands, but these will give you what you are looking for.
PS: Most Caribbean islands you can snorkel right off the beaches.